# How to set loop through sheets listed in setting?

Tags: excel, vba

I created my macro using tips here, but it does not work. Having a list of sheets at my setting page, I need to loop through those sheets listed here only. If I declare sheet via its name, it works. Problem is when I tried to use range.

I cannot activate List. In VBA I can see its value by mouse pointer (99), but it does not work. My last name is List2 (99) in VBA; 99 is visible for the user. (I am using excel 365 in czech language)

```
Dim List As Range
Dim Listy As Range
Set Listy = Sheets("Setting").Range("A2:A3")

For Each List In Listy
    Sheets("99").Activate        ' this is working

    Sheets(List).Activate        'this is not working

    Sheets(List.Value).Activate 'this is not working

    Sheets(List.Name).Activate  'this is not working
    '... rest of my code
next list
```

I expect I can activate Sheet 99 using range Listy instead of its names.

Comment: `Sheets(List.Value).Activate` this should work, unless the name in that cell is something not present as sheet name.

Comment: Have a look at why we shouldn't use things like `Activate` and/or `Select` in VBA. Just set your sheet/cell references. You don't need to activate or select either of them

Comment: @Mikku, @Zac, the issue isn't about `Activate`. The `List.Value` is an integer, and so the Sheet interprets this as an index, rather than a name. So we have to convert that to a String first. I was able to reproduce the problem and gave an answer below.

Comment: @AAA: your answer may work but it doesn't mean it's good practice. Normally, there is no need to activate or select a sheet when working with VBA. I'm sure there are situations here it's **"needed"** but this certainly doesn't look like one. I was just trying to point out to OP that this action is not needed and is not best practice

Comment: @Zac, that would not solve the OP's problem. Even if the OP were to use Sheet references, they would still get the error. You first solve the problem, then point out best practices. This is a skeleton code, so you don't know why the OP is using Activate. The problem they have is with **referencing** the Sheet, as I explain in my answer.

Comment: @AAA: this will be my last msg as I don't want this to be a discussion. The point here is, if OP sets the reference to the sheet, they will not have to activate the sheet.. that's the answer. How the reference is set, that you have kinda answered. In this instance, advice almost solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

the second iteration, when you added ".value" to list is the closest you got... I would suggest you try to use **Sheets(list.value).select** instead of Activate. Never had a problem with the former, while the latter I tend to use it for workbooks.

See if that sorts it out:

Dim List As Range Dim Listy As Range 
  Set Listy = Sheets("Setting").Range("A2:A3")

For Each List In Listy

sheets(List.Value).select ***'TRY THIS!***
  Next

Comment: Your answer will be easier to understand if you format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your range is returning Integer values. Therefore, the `Sheet(index)` call interprets index to be the index number of the sheet. So rather than calling `Sheet("99"), you are actually calling Sheet(99). Since you do not have a 99th sheet in your Workbook, you get a "Subscript out of range" error. What we need to do is to convert your values to Strings.

This is what you should do:

```vb
Dim Listy As Range
Set Listy = Sheets("Setting").Range("A2:A3")

For Each cell In Listy
    Sheets(CStr(cell.Value)).Activate        
Next cell
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195885/discussion-on-answer-by-aaa-how-to-set-loop-through-sheets-listed-in-setting).